# Search all differences between two directories

Tags: linux, command-line

I have modified a third party bundle and I want to know all changes I've done.
What linux command can give me that? I guess should use diff command, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got the original source in src/ and your modified version in my_src/, you can use diff with the --recursive switch:

```
 diff --recursive src my_src
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the GUI replacements of `diff` like [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/).

## UPDATE

You might want to try and take a look at [mtree](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree).

Comment: I'd like to do with command line. Maybe something like this: $ find Directory1/* -type f | xargs diff Directory2 (this doesn't work).